# Mark post as read in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to add class (in index) to entry that are been read.

It is possible?

What is best way to do this? Use cookie or session?

I need little help with this ;)

Comment: How can you accurately determine whether a user has a read a post or not? Hint: you can't.

Comment: @AmalMurali you certainly can :)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple by setting a cookie, you could use the post ID to refer to the post you need to be marked as read. So when clicking mark as read link on the page with the entry just set up a cookie with the post ID and do a check on the overview page if there is a cookie with the post ID of the posts shown.

More about cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Also, there seems to be a plugin who can actually do this for you, go take a look at http://pippinsplugins.com/mark-as-read-for-wordpress/

Comment: you can also use Javascript Cookies (w3school) on post-template. Store the ID of post in cookies and when next time post-template loaded show the client (visitor) that this post is already read.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply :)
In top of single.php I add something like this: `<?php echo'
 <script>
  function setCookie(name, value, expires) {
   var cookieStr = escape(name) +"=";
   if (typeof value != "undefined") {
    cookieStr += escape(value);
   }
   if (!expires) {
    expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime()+60*60*400000);
   }
   cookieStr += "; expires="+ expires.toGMTString() +";";
   document.cookie = cookieStr;
  };

  setCookie("mark_read", '; echo get_the_ID(); echo ');
 </script>'
?>`

Cookie is created but how to add class to specific post in index?